# Sharepoint file type check before convert to pdf

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, sharepoint-library, modern-document-library

I face an issue here where I have a list where user need to submit their file with some information there. Once it is approve, there will be a backend power automate flow that will convert the file to pdf.

But here's the problem, the submission of attachment in list can be in any file type. Is there any way where to update power automate flow to do checking?

Condition:

If the file/s is .pdf then skip file conversion, just pull the document from list to library along with the details of information?

If the file/s is others, then convert to .pdf and update the details of information.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the answer after a few rounds of testing. This is my flow:

1. When an item is created (properties only)
2. Get file content (At this stage I select Identifier)
3. I will have a condition to check the file type.

   triggerOutputs()?['body/{FilenameWithExtension}']|ends with| .pdf

If the condition match then it will skip the conversion, if the document are not .pdf then it will proceed with the next steps.